# Can I create a block like of CiviCRM autocomplete search using "Search AutoComplete" module?

Tags: search, quicksearch

Can I create a block like of CiviCRM autocomplete search using "Search AutoComplete" module?

https://www.drupal.org/project/search_autocomplete

I have tried to figure out but cant seem to work it out? anyone tried, any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1):

A very speedy google on 'drupal autocomplete block' turned up many modules that will help you. Plug in the results of a civicrm api call, remembering to set count=0 to sidestep the 25 result limit. If you get stuck on a specific part then please reply!

Comment: Thanks for your input. Actually I realised i can call  civicrm contacts using the module I have mentioned in this post. But since I have two different Db fir civi and drupal the module can't reach the civicrm tables. Is there any complication of merging two db? The method you are suggesting, do I need to do any php coding?

Comment: That's a separate question, but it sounds like you might need to visit `civicrm/admin/setting/uf?reset=1` (Administer => System Settings => CMS Database Integration) where I think you'll get instructions on configuring the aliases in your settings.php. Or you can merge the DBs as you suggest.